# Directive does not work in bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a basic angular directive to get focus on elements. It works fine in different pages, but it does not work in modal dialog which I created with Bootstrap components.

my directive is :

```
myApp.directive('focus', function () {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('directive ' + element);
        angular.element(element).focus();

    }
};
```

});

thanks for any help

Comment: add setTimeout to focus  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myApp.directive('focus', function () {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('directive ' + element);
        setTimeout(function(){angular.element(element).focus();}, 200);

    }
};
```

when you try to set the focus, the element is not yet visible

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and found that the native HTML [`autofocus`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control:-the-autofocus-attribute) attribute works like a charm.

```
<button autofocus>Example</button>
```